# Why do I get a TypeError: no implicit conversion of symbol into Integer?

Tags: ruby

I am playing around with nested hashes. Task:

> Create three hashes called `person1`, `person2`, and `person3`, with first
>   and last names under the keys `:first` and `:last`. Then create a params
>   hash so that `params[:father]` is `person1`, `params[:mother]` is `person2`,
>   and `params[:child]` is `person3`. Verify that, for example,
>   `params[:father][:first]` has the right value.

My solution:

```
person1 = {first: "first_name1", last: "last_name1"}
person2 = {first: "first_name2", last: "last_name2"}
person3 = {first: "first_name3", last: "last_name3"}
params = { :father => ":person1", :mother => ":person2", :child => ":person3" }
```

then `params[:father][:first]` gives

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of symbol into Integer

Why? I don't understand why I get the TypeError.

Comment: parameter access key value pair params = { :father => "person1", :mother => ":person2", :child => "person3" } and access params[:father] give result  "person1"

Comment: That is understood. It was passing more than one argument I was confused about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you assign values to the `params` hash keys, you supply strings instead of `personx` hashes. The proper way would be instead of

```
params = { :father => ":person1"...
```

do

```
params = { :father => person1...
```

The reason for the error is as follows. This line:

```
params[:father][:first]
```

fetches the value of `params[:father]` first. You expect this value to be a hash, but due to the syntax error above it is a string. `String` does implement `[]` method just like hash but its semantics is different. It accesses a character within a string by its integer index. It expects the index to be passed as an argument to `[]`.

Since you pass a symbol instead, `[:first]`, and there is no default way to convert a symbol to integer, you get the appropriate error:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of symbol into Integer

Comment: For some reason, it was the string "" that got me confused about the syntax.  I understand now.

Comment: Or you could `params = { father: person1, mother: person2,  child: "person 3"}`

https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/TypeError.html

Answer (score 0):

Use those variables names. Like below:

```
params = { :father => person1, :mother => person2, :child => person3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting this error was the following...

Instead of doing this

```
<%= form.fields_for :terms, term do |term_form| %>
```

I was doing this...

```
<%= form.fields_for :terms_attributes, term do |term_form| %>
```